Powershell script: I have a CSV that I get with a list of emails, Manager emails. I want to turn that into an outlook email script that emails each
I want to be able to loop through each email on the CSV under the User column and send an email to each user + manager separately. So it should be Manager + User on 1 email for each new column.
Clear-Host
Start-Transcript
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Filter File--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
$CSV = "Main.CSV"  # creates a variable with the File location
$EmptyColumns = "Hired", "Manager Email" # Picks the columns with empty spaces to parse through
$trimfile= "Trim_Main.CSV"
$filterDate = (get-date).AddDays(1)
$data = import-csv $CSV | Where-Object{   
 # Removes the rows with blank columns   # Imports the file
$line = $_
($EmptyColumns| ForEach-Object{
![string]::IsNullOrEmpty(($line.$_.Trim("""")))
}) -notcontains $false
}

$selectedData = $data | select-object -Property 

'User',"Manager Email", "Hired"     #This Selects the data from the imported file

 $selectedData | Where-Object {$_.Hired -as [dateTime] -lt 
 $filterDate} | Export-csv $trimfile 

#This filters the columns where the datetime is lt then todays date. Exports that filter file.
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Users = import-csv -path $trimfileTest

$ol = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application  
$mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)  
Mail.To = ("$Users")
$Mail.Subject = "PS1 Script TestMail"  
$Mail.Body = "  
Test Mail  
"  
 $Mail.Send()`

| We need to know who to send this to. Make sure you enter at least one name.
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
this is the error that I get. Like it cant read the columns or something

The error tells you that no recipients were added. You can set To/CC/BCC properties to a ";"-separated list of names/emails or call MailItem.Recipients.Add for each recipient.
Your current code seems to be calling To() method, which does not exist on the MailItem object - To is a read/write property.

I want each recipient to be added via the cvs file. Separately

Then you need to loop through all entries and call $Mail.Recipients.Add($MyAddressFromCSV) for each value or build a ";" separated string of all the addresses and assign it to the $Mail.To property once.
